# pointfree add to list in haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm trying to derive function of three args, using simple function chaining.

The function should be of type

```
addToList :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
```

and be pointfree analogue of

```
addToList :: a b c = (a : (b : (c : [])))
```

So far, I've figured out

```
addToList = ((.)((.) (flip (:)) . (flip (:))) . (flip (:))) []
```

But it works in reverse:

```
Prelude> addToList 4 5 6
[6,5,4]
```

and looks bulky.

How can one get something nice like

```
(.) (.) (.) (:) (:) (: [])
```

that works as follows:

```
Prelude> addToList 4 5 6
[4,5,6]
```

?

Comment: You could simply use [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) which yields: `addToList = (. ((. return) . (:))) . (.) . (:)`

Comment: And that's so much more clear than `addToList a b c = [a,b,c]`. \*sigh\*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at a more general version, that uses three functions `f`, `g` and `h`:

```
func a b c = f a (g b (h c))
```

In our case, `f = (:)`, `g = (:)` and `h = return`, but we can use this for any triple of functions that follow the same scheme:

```
func a b c = (f a . g b . h) c
```

For the next step, write the first application of `(.)` in prefix form, so that it's easier to combine `(.) (f a)` and the rest later:

```
func a b = (.) (f a) (g b . h)
         = (.) (f a) (g b . h)
         = (.) (f a) ((.) (g b) h)
         = (.) (f a) (flip (.) h (g b))
         = (.) (f a) ((flip (.) h . g) b)
         = (.) (f a) . (flip (.) h . g) b
```

We can now do the same for `a`:

```
func a = (.) (f a) . (flip (.) h . g)
       = (.) ((.) (f a)) (flip (.) h . g)
       = flip (.) (flip (.) h . g) ((.) (f a))
       = flip (.) (flip (.) h . g) . (.) (f a)
       = flip (.) (flip (.) h . g) . (.) . f a
```

Since `flip (.) x` is `(.x)` we can get rid of `flip`:

```
func = flip (.) (flip (.) h . g) . (.) . f
     = flip (.) ((.h) . g) . (.) . f
     = (.((.h) . g)) . (.) . f
```

All we have to do now is to insert the definitions of `f`, `g` and `h`:

```
func = (.((.return) . (:))) . (.) . (:)
```

I didn't check whether there is a shorter version, but since this is the same result as [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) yields, it should be more or less optimal.

That being said, if you compare

```
addToList = (.((.return) . (:))) . (.) . (:)
```

with

```
addToList a b c = [a, b, c]
```

which one would you like to read in three months?

Answer (score 0):

Just playing with this a little, maybe it will give you some ideas...

```
-- | >>> append [4,5] 6
-- [4,5,6]
append :: [a] -> a -> [a]
append = flip (flip (++) . (: []))

-- | >>> f1 4
-- [4]
f1 :: a -> [a]
f1 = (:[])

-- | >>> f2 4 5
-- [4,5]
f2 :: a -> a -> [a]
f2 = append . f1

-- | >>> f3 4 5 6
-- [4,5,6]
f3 :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
f3 = (append .) . f2

-- | >>> f4 4 5 6 7
-- [4,5,6,7]
f4 :: a -> a -> a -> a -> [a]
f4 = ((append .) .) . f3
```